# Scale containers for different ip addreses using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose.

```
version: '2'
services:
  mockup:
    build: mockup/
    ports:
      - 12320:12320
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/tt/:/var/lib/tt/
    networks:
      - test

networks:
   test:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24
            gateway: 172.20.1.1
```

I want to deploy a few instances of the same application on different containers and different IP addreses.
When I run docker-compose up --scale mockup=2 or more there is conflict on the port. All deployed apps must be on the same port.
What should I change in my docker-compose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to scale without having an issue with the port you need to make it bind on a random port so you need to do like below, it will make the host port random for each container you start and map it to `12320` which inside the container:

```
ports:
  - 12320
```

Next you should use some kind of service discovery to be aware of the new containers as you go up or down and a proxy so you can talk to a specific URL without worrying about which container is up and what is the port